# laravel form doesn't want to send data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, save

So i'm trying to save date from this form to my database using laravel but when I test it using print-r
it shows that the form doesn't send anything and I couldn't figure where the problem is ?

View

```
<form  action="{{ route('auctioneer.save') }}" method="POST">
@csrf
      <fieldset>
  

          <div class="form-group" style="width: 35%; position: absolute; margin-left: 4%">
              <fieldset>
                <label class="control-label" for="readOnlyInput">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="readOnlyInput" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" readonly="" style="width: 100%">
              </fieldset>
            </div>

            
              <div class="form-group"  style="width: 35%;margin-left: 60%">
                  <fieldset>
                    <label class="control-label" for="readOnlyInput">email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="readOnlyInput" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" readonly="" style="width: 100%">
                  </fieldset>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group"  style="width: 35%; position: absolute; margin-left: 4%">
              <label for="entreprisepos">Position dans l'entreprise</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="entreprisePos" aria-describedby="aucti" placeholder="Commercial ...">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group"   style="width: 35%;margin-left: 60%">
              <label for="entrepriseNom">Nom du l'entreprise</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="entrepriseNom" aria-describedby="aucti" placeholder="Make it Happen ...">
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="termsChkbx " type="checkbox" value="" checked=""  onchange="isChecked(this, 'sub1')">
                I Agree on <a href="https://www.termsandcondiitionssample.com/"> Terms and Conditions </a>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="ps-btn" id="sub1"  style="width: 20%;"  value="Submit">
                Submit Form
              </button>  
            </div>          
          </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/submitauct','AuctioneerController@save')->name('auctioneer.save');
```

Controller

```
 public function save( Request $req){

    print_r($req->input());

}
```

Display

Array ( [_token] => xNY3q1BvlxuT3zylwhtONx0Xv13qVPUhrrga8omo )

Comment: None of your inputs has the `name` attribute, you need that so your form can send value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss the name attribute in  tag your data is pass in request but doesnot get any name so you didint see the data
always remamber id is usefull when you work with frontend like js/jquery/css but when you want to work in backend you have to passs name attribute.

next mistake is always use  not button when you want to submit form in laravel.
use button when you want to submit form using ajax or axios its good.

hint:in dd() token is print becuase when you use @csrf you get this.

it has by default name property so it shows

pleas if this is helpful vote up..................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from HTML form, you need use input attribute name.

```
<input name="foo" value="bar">
```

Then you can get the value in Laravel :

```
request()->input('foo');
```